# Typescript - Base an interface from a class

Tags: interface, typescript, polymorphism

The following code generates errors because of the private attribute e1. I wonder if the e1 is part of the interface I. I thought an interface is all about public elememts. May I know how to fix the code to make it to work (or how to base an interface on a class with private attributes.

Thanks for your helps,

Andre

```
class A {
        constructor(private e1: string, public e2: string) {}
    public displayValue(): string {
        return this.e1 + ":" + this.e2;
    }
}

interface I extends A {
    e3: string;
    displayValue2(): string;
}

class IA implements I {
    constructor(public e2: string, public e3: string, private e4: string) {}

    public displayValue(): string {
        return this.e2 + ":" + this.e3 + ":" + this.e4;
    }

    public displayValue2(): string {
        return "testing";
    }
}

var f: (a: A) => void = function(a: A) {
    console.log(a);
}

var a1: A = new A("teste1", "teste2");
var a2: IA = new IA("testiae2", "testiae3", "testiae4");

f(a1);
f(a2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript it is possible to "extend" a class while defining an interface, in this interface you will have all the members from the extended class including private, public, and protected.

try to do this:

```
var i: I;
i. // <-- The IDE will show you ONLY the public members of I, but will know about the privates
```

BUT, behind the scenes TypeScript "Knows" that this interface has some private members, this is why it will tell you that **"e2"** property is missing on **"IA"**.

If you implement **"I"** you must take that into account, just like you would if a you would extend **"A"** (That has the private member)

Comment: Thanks Gilamran for your tips. And I modify the code as follows and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    constructor(private e1: string, public e2: string) {}
    public displayValue(): string {
        return this.e1 + ":" + this.e2;
    }
}

interface I extends A {
    e3: string;
    displayValue2(): string;
}

var i: I;

class IA extends A implements I {
    constructor(public e3: string, private e4: string, e1: string, e2: string) {
        super(e1, e2);
    }

    public displayValue(): string {
        return this.e2 + ":" + this.e3 + ":" + this.e4;
    }

    public displayValue2(): string {
        return "testing";
    }
}

var f: (a: A) => void = function(a: A) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(a.displayValue());
}

var a1: A = new A("teste1", "teste2");
var a2: IA = new IA("testiae2", "testiae3", "testiae4", "testiae1");

f(a1);
f(a2);
```